# Excel Function to Max out a cell before moving to the next cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, formula, subtraction

How to subtract a value from a cell until it reaches zero (or a certain number) and then reduce the remaining amount from another cell? I have been researching and found out that the MAX function can be helpful, however I don't understand how to use it.

Example:

```
Leave Requested: 12 hours
Bank A: 8 hours
Bank B: 15 hours
```

The requirement is for the employee to be paid 8 hours from Bank A (until it reaches zero) and then pay the remaining hours, i.e. 4 hours, from Bank B and then show the balance of (15-4) 11 hours in Bank B. Is there a function for this in excel?

Comment: It can't be done in place, you will need to put the results in different cells or use vba.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, if you want to get the results next to the values, something like this works:

[image]

B2: `=MAX(0,A2-A1)`
B3: `=A3-A1+A2-B2`

Comment: Thank You. That was helpful... But, I used IF condition for C2 to consider the scenarios for when Bank A has not been maxed out.

Comment: Sorry - by C2 I meant B3 so that it corresponds to the image. There should be no need for an IF statement?

Comment: An easy algebraic way to think about it....the total in the bank in the beginning, minus the withdrawal will equal the balance at the end, or A2+A3-A1 = B2+B3. Rearrange it and B3 = A2+A3-A1-B2. If the person asks for 2 hours off, the calculation in B2 will account for that and make the balance 6, and B3 will still be 15.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a set of banks in column **A** and their initial capacities in column **B** like this:

[image]

Place the request in cell **E1**.  In cell **C2** enter:

```
=MAX(0,B2-E1)
```

In **C3** enter:

```
=MAX(0,B3-D2)
```

and copy down.  In **D2** enter:

```
=MAX(0,E1-B2)
```

In **D3** enter:

```
=MAX(0,D2-B3)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Column **C** represents the balance in the bank after the debit.  Column **D** represents the balance in the request after the debit.